# How to compute the difference between two dates/time in terms of trading days?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Lets say I select two times in the 10 min timeframe as following:

```
p1 = input.price(0, "P-1", confirm=true,group = "1",inline = "1")
input_time_1  = input.time(0, "T-1",          confirm=true,group = "1",inline = "1")

p2 = input.price(0, "P-2", confirm=true,group = "2",inline = "2")
input_time_2  = input.time(0, "T-2",          confirm=true,group = "2",inline = "2")
```

How can I compute the trading days between these two days?

Basically, if we consider the following picture the blue vertical lines are the selected lines, and what I expect is the number of trading days which in this case should be 34 days.

[image]

Comment: Are you going to always use this with inputs?

Comment: yes, It will be for custom range between two times. Why would that matter?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do that, using the `timeframe.in_seconds()` function.

```
p1 = input.price(0, "P-1", confirm=true,group = "1",inline = "1")
input_time_1  = input.time(0, "T-1",          confirm=true,group = "1",inline = "1")

p2 = input.price(0, "P-2", confirm=true,group = "2",inline = "2")
input_time_2  = input.time(0, "T-2",          confirm=true,group = "2",inline = "2")

barsBetween = (input_time_2 - input_time_1) / (timeframe.in_seconds() * 1000)

if barstate.islast
    label.new(input_time_2,high,str.tostring(barsBetween),yloc = yloc.abovebar, xloc = xloc.bar_time, color=color.aqua)
```

[image: bars between]